# Iron Man repulsor question

Tags: particle-physics

Ignoring the whole movie situation along with the power demands, what do you think Iron Man's repulsors use to "repulse" his targets? I don't think they are lasers or electric beams, or "reverse magnetism", but I'm guessing its some sort of focused sonic waave or a shock wave generator.

Answer (score 2):

I bet it's imagination. In imagination-land everything is possible :-)

In reality them most compact & efficient are conventional weapons.
Then probably only 10kW CO2 laser, which is real, but not as cool as in movie.

Comment: I know its fake, but if there were to be a real suit, which would it use? Like a sonic or pressure wave.

Comment: If it were real, we would stop on nuclear fusion :-) This alone already can make all physicists happy. :-) 

This weapon - could be compressed air blow, but it's sounds like a joke :-) Also, in reality any weapon of this kind would have corresponding 'kickback'...

Comment: Obviously you would use pressure waves to “absorb” the kickback along with the vibrations :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by BarsMonster ,newton's Third law says the iron man will be acted upon by the equal and opposite force which he is exerting on any body. Hence its just mere imagination.

Comment: well the opposite force can always be cancelled with an electronically controlled thrust

Comment: But I guess they dont show it happening. Hence does not apply to iron man

Comment: in some of the comics they said he had some way of locking his arms into place and lowering his center of gravity

Comment: Are you trying to explain above phenomenon or its something unrelated you are talking about

Comment: as in by locking his arms and lowering his center of gravity, he wasn't as affected by the reaction to the repulsor blast. In the movie he gets blasted backwards by it too, so there is some sort of knockback despite what people say